# Segregate and arrange data in specific format in Angular?

Tags: json, for-loop, angular5

Hi I am developing Angular 5 application. I am trying to arrange data in specific format. I have json data. I want to convert it to specific format.

Below is the specific format.

```
 this.nodes = [

      {
        name: 'root1',
        children: [
          { name: 'child1' }
        ]
      },

      {
        name: 'root2',
        hasChildren: true
      },

      {
        name: 'root3'
      }

    ];
```

Below is my data.

```
   {  
       "userid":"e75792f8-cfea-460e-aca2-07a778c92a7c",
       "tenantid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
       "username":"karthik",
       "emailaddress":"john@krsars.onmicrosoft.com",
       "isallowed":false,
       "userroles":[  
          {  
             "userroleid":"b81e63d1-09da-4aa0-af69-0f086ddb20b4",
             "userid":"e75792f8-cfea-460e-aca2-07a778c92a7c",
             "roleid":"85d2f668-f523-4b64-b177-b1a78db74234",
             "tenantappid":1,
             "validfrom":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
             "validto":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
             "isactive":true,
          }
       ]
    }
```

From the above data, I am trying to convert. From the above data each key/value pair I am converting it to format above given, For example, "userid":"e75792f8-cfea-460e-aca2-07a778c92a7c" I want to make it as

```
 {
        name: 'userid',
         children: [
           { name: 'e75792f8-cfea-460e-aca2-07a778c92a7c' }
         ]
 }
```

So below I is my code.

```
 for (let key in results) {
     if(results[key] instanceof Array){
        this.nodes+=
          name:key,
          hasChildren: true
        }+"}"
     }
     else
     {
       this.nodes+="{"+name=key,
       children: [
        { name: results[key] }
      ]+"}"
     }
    }
```

Finally When i tried to display my data in console.

```
console.log(this.nodes);
```

Above my code does not work. Can someone help me to make this work? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. Just to show you which way to go:

```
doIt() {
    let results =  JSON.parse('{"userid":"e75792f8-cfea-460e-aca2-07a778c92a7c","tenantid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","username":"karthik","emailaddress":"john@krsars.onmicrosoft.com","isallowed":false,"userroles":[{"userroleid":"b81e63d1-09da-4aa0-af69-0f086ddb20b4","userid":"e75792f8-cfea-460e-aca2-07a778c92a7c","roleid":"85d2f668-f523-4b64-b177-b1a78db74234","tenantappid":1,"validfrom":"2018-01-24T00:00:00","validto":"2018-01-24T00:00:00","isactive":true}]}');

     const nodes = [];

     for (const key in results) {
         if (results[key] instanceof Array) {
           const containerTyp2 = {name: '', hasChildren: false};

           containerTyp2.name = key;
           containerTyp2.hasChildren = true;

           nodes.push(containerTyp2);
        } else {
           const object = {name: ''};
           const containerTyp1 = {name: '', children: []};

           object.name = key;
           containerTyp1.name = key;
           containerTyp1.children.push(object);

           nodes.push(containerTyp1);
       }
     }

     console.log('nodes: ', nodes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work Lynx. I am following https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/blob/master/example/cli/src/app/async/async.component.ts to display data in same way they are displaying. The code you have written will convert the data in format required exactly. But data is not displaying tree format nor giving any errors too. If i put data they have given it displays. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: This will take a while to check. I'll get back to you.

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding  this.tree.treeModel.update(); Thanks for your effort. It is working like charm now.